# Upload HTML website files to Openshift PHP 5.4

Tags: php, html, git, openshift, filezilla

This is my first website (website itself is all done).  I'm trying to upload my website files to my Openshift PHP 5.4 domain so when I click my OpenShift domain url, my website appears (pretty simple, right?).  My Openshift account is set up.  I've connected to it with FileZilla, and set up a private (or public) key.  I've installed Ruby & Git.  I followed everything [here](https://developers.openshift.com/getting-started/windows.html#client-tools), and am stuck on this step:

*Web Console*

If you create an application from the web console, you’ll need to tell Git to clone the repository. Find the Git URL from the application page, and then run:

```
C:\> git clone <git_url> <directory to create>
```

I don't know what the "git_url" is supposed to be.  Nor do I know what the "directory to create" is supposed to be.  I don't know what [OpenShift directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1csi.jpg) to put my website files in (when I connect with FileZilla) so that when I open my OpenShift domain url, I see my website (see below).

Again, my goal is to see my website when I open my OpenShift PHP 5.4 url.  Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't know what git is about, I recommend that you go read about it: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started

If you have your site ready and you've created an OpenShift app, do the following:

1) Grab the git url (you can find it by browsing to https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications, clicking your app, and then copying the long address on the right, under "Source Code"), it should look something like this: `ssh://afa231av@app-domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/app.git/`

2) Open up a terminal (or use some git ui tool) and clone (download) your app with

```
git clone ssh://afa231av@app-domain.rhcloud.com/~/git/app.git
```

3) You should have a folder named `app`, now use the file explorer go inside it and paste in all your website

4) Go back to the terminal and do

```
cd app (or whatever name your app has)
git add .
git commit -m "Add my website"
git push origin master
```

Wait for it to finish, and if there are no errors, you're all done.

Comment: Thank you.  [This is what I did.](http://i.imgur.com/jvGwbRi.jpg)  The "app" folder you're talking about is named "php", right?  I had done 'git clone ssh://.....' correctly previously.  Still didn't see my website up.  [Did this.](http://i.imgur.com/m8VzJAi.jpg)  Still don't see my website up.

Comment: Instead of trying to add your whole website there, start with a smaller example just so you understand what's going on; start by editing the index.php file that comes with the repo, and try to add another file and create some url to it or something like that. Then add, commit and push those changes and see if you can make sense of it.

Answer (score 1):

git_url: Go to OpenShift Web Console -> Application -> find and click your application, on the right there is Source Code panel with something like ssh://***.rhcloud.com/~/git/php.git/, this will be your git_url

directory_to_create: is just a name of directory that will be created that will contain your git repo on your local file system

When you clone this repo, you should copy your files to it, then commit and push to branch named 'master', and it will be automatically deployed on server.

Comment: Thank you!  I've completed the "git clone" step.  How do I "copy my files to it"?  In FileZilla?  The directories appear to be the same as my OP pic.

Comment: When I did "git add ." I got "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git".

Comment: I'm so lost.  I tried "git init", then copied my website files to C:/Users/.../.git folder (probably wrong too).  Then I did "git add ." and it added a whole bunch of junk from my AppData/Local folder (I think).  Many files were "Filename too long".  Then, I uploaded my website files to the "php.git" folder in FileZilla (probably wrong directory).  Then I "git commit -m "master"" (I put master).  Then git remote add master http://php-mywebsite.rhcloud.com/.  Then git push master, then fatal error.  Then "git push --set-upstream master master".

Comment: Now I have an error: src refspec master does not match any.  error: failed to push some refs to 'http://php-mywebsite.rhcloud.com'.  How does anyone ever figure this out?

Comment: You don't need FileZilla at all. I suggest for you to configure some kind of graphical UI Git Client, for example SourceTree. Download and install SourceTree, then you have to upload your private ssh key in options (use: OpenSSH). http://i.stack.imgur.com/h3reJ.png, and you can clone repository using git_url. And then you can copy your files to repo, and push and commit by using buttons in this program, that could be much easier for you than using command line.